# React Leaflet map to PDF

Tags: reactjs, pdf-generation, react-leaflet

I can generate `PNG` file by using

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-easyprint

I need to generate **`PDF`** from **`PNG`** file.

How can I prevent download of the file and use this content to generate PDF file before download PNG file?

Is there maybe better library for this purpose?

There is also an option to use nodeJs and phantomJs, but in this case there will be code duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leaflet-easyprint library leverages the dom-to-image library.

https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint/blob/gh-pages/src/index.js#L127

I suggest copying a bit of the code from there and using dom-to-image + filesaver to convert the dom to a base64 blob export as a pdf.

https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image#usage

Answer (score 1):

For reference:

I used a combination of dom-to-image library and https://react-pdf.org/

Got a reference of the map, got its container. And passed it into dom-to-image and used the result in the reactPdf. I used an A4 landscape size and orientation.

```
const _a4PageSize= { height: 715, width: 1045 }
domtoimage
  .toPng(mapRef.current.leafletElement.getContainer(), _a4PageSize)
  .then(dataUrl => {
    //pass dataUrl to reactpdf document here
  })
  .catch(err => console.log("to img err", err));
```

// reactpdf document

```
  <Document >          
    <Page size="A4" orientation="landscape">
        <Image src={{uri: dataUrl}}/>            
    </Page> 
  </Document>
```